# How to upload an iOS App to iTunes Connect for testing with XCode 8.2.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am using latest XCode 8.2.1 and try to upload my application for testing to iTunes Connect to share it with TestFlight.

I am using "Automatic Code Signing" in "General" settings. I am able to deploy my application on a connected iOS device.

**What I have tried:**

In XCode I choosed "Product => Archive" and then I selected "Save for Development Deployment". I have also created a "manifest.plist" to share the ipa file over a special web page.

This step is processed successfully and I have a valid ipa file for sharing. The sharing is also working when a known device want to install the application over the air on a special web page "manifest.plist" (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html)

- To upload the ipa file to iTunes Connect I choose "XCode => Open Developer Tool => Application Loader".
- In opened window I click on "Choose" and select the created ipa file from archive exporting process.

**The Issue**

This step returns with the error message:
"ERROR ITMS:90161: 'Invalid Provisioning Profile: The provisioning profile included in the bundle xxx.xxx is invalid. (Missing code-signing certificate). A Distribution Provisioning Profil should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. Bla bla"

From another answer I know:

"In Xcode 8, Automatic Signing is going to manage profiles, entitlements and certificates for you, but only for Development. If you select automatic, you are forced to use Development signing and Xcode-created provisioning profiles.

On the WWDC 2016 (Session 401 - What's new in Xcode app signing) they explain this new signing method and describe some 'Best Practices'. When you are building for distribution and using Automatic Signing or Manual you should Archive for Development and then export (from the organizer or the command line tools xcodebuild -exportArchive) as Distribution. The organizer will re-sign your app for Distribution even if it was archived for Development."
([Xcode 8.0 Automatically Manage Signing behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440403/xcode-8-0-automatically-manage-signing-behaviour))

**Question**

How to force the organizer or what ever to sign the app with the Distribution Profile? Of cource there is one in Apple Developer Account but it seems that XCode 8 is not able to select it.

Comment: _and then I selected "Save for Development Deployment"_ Why? If you want to upload the archive to iTunes Connect, Xcode can do it for you, directly from the archive, can't it?

Comment: _Furthermore it is a pain to develop applications on MacOs and XCode_ Please confine your question to your question. If you want to whine, do it on your blog or something.

Comment: @matt sorry for that, but it costs me hours for doing simple things in XCode. It is really frustrating. However, how should I submit the archive directly to iTunes Connect? I find no option in XCode 8. This tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/testflight-beta-testing/ is outdated.

Comment: Have you created the entry for this app at iTunes Connect?

Comment: @matt Yes, I have performed all steps described in http://www.appcoda.com/testflight-beta-testing/ until the step where I should submit the archive to iTunes Connect. But in latest XCode there is no "Submit" button anymore.

Comment: Yes there is. — Did you make an App Store distribution profile and download and install it?

Comment: BTW, pretty good description in Apple's docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH36 I would suggest going through that carefully.

Comment: @matt Well provided link also does not show a "Submit" button but only a "Upload to App Store..." button. Is this the same? App Store and iTunes Connect is the same? I am confused...

Comment: Yes they both are same. Once you upload the app to iTunes Connect and your app successfully gets verified by Apple, you can use it for TestFlight.

Comment: Yes, what Prerak Sola said.