# How to get a distribution app when using xcodebuild -exportArchive (Xcode8.3, Auto Signing)?

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcodebuild

After update Xcode8.3, the options '*-exportSigningIdentity*', '*-exportProvisioningProfile*' and '*-exportFormat*' are removed from  '*xcodebuild -exportArchive*'.

When i try to get a distribution app, i get the error below:
 *xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-exportProvisioningProfile'.*

So how can i get distribution MyApp.ipa from MyApp.xcarchive, when the project has set Automatic Signing Enabled?

[Automatic Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440403/xcode-8-0-automatically-manage-signing-behaviour)

Comment: A few things changed in xcodebuild. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43147906/171933

Comment: thanx,   i have noticed that . my point is how to get a .ipa for app store in build system~

Comment: The steps that I've outlined in my answer should spit out an ipa at the end!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create an IPA on the command line from an existing xcarchive. Since Xcode 7, the preferred way to do this is (from `man xcodebuild`):

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath xcarchivepath -exportPath destinationpath -exportOptionsPlist path
```

So in your case:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath MyApp.xcarchive -exportPath MyApp.ipa -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

exportOptions.plist is a PLIST file that contains various parameters configuring the IPA export. See `xcodebuild -help` for all available options. You'll have to at least specifiy an entry for `method` (app-store, ad-hoc, enterprise etc. - defaults to development). If you just want to export for App-Store distribution, the file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I converted my command lines and everything works except push ... i am not sure it use good provisioning profile ... i have lot of targets with différents provisioning profile in my project and I tried to find a solution for 2 days... nothing. Will install older version of xCode ..

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this parameter :

-exportProvisioningProfile "MyProvisioningProfile"

with:

PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="MyProvisioningProfile"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `Automatic Signing Enabled` Xcode will automatically generate according provisioning profile.

But in order to make your command working you need to manually export the archive the first time.
Once it is done, Xcode will generate the provisioning profile (it starts by "XC" in the Apple Developer website).

Then your `xcodebuild` command will work.

**Product** -> **Archive**

Once it's done

**Windows** -> **Organizer** -> **Select the last version** -> **Export** (right pannel under **Upload to App Store**)

Keep me inform if you need additional informations.

Comment: If i use build system(like jenkins),  How can this work?

Comment: It will work once you have done it at least one time manually. In order to make Xcode generate your provisioning profile.