# How to create IPA using terminal

Tags: swift3, xcode8, xcodebuild

I'm using XCode 8.3. if I fire this command in Terminal for making an archive as shown below. It shows this kind of error. Can you help me to find out the solution?

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "/Users/Desktop/Demo.xcarchive" -exportPath "/Users/Desktop/Demo.ipa" -exportProvisioningProfile "Demo Development"

xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-exportFormat'

Usage: xcodebuild [-project <projectname>] [[-target <targetname>]...|-alltargets] [-configuration <configurationname>] [-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] [-showBuildSettings] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...
  xcodebuild [-project <projectname>] -scheme <schemeName> [-destination <destinationspecifier>]... [-configuration <configurationname>] [-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] [-showBuildSettings] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...
  xcodebuild -workspace <workspacename> -scheme <schemeName> [-destination <destinationspecifier>]... [-configuration <configurationname>] [-arch <architecture>]... [-sdk [<sdkname>|<sdkpath>]] [-showBuildSettings] [<buildsetting>=<value>]... [<buildaction>]...
  xcodebuild -version [-sdk [<sdkfullpath>|<sdkname>] [<infoitem>] ]
  xcodebuild -list [[-project <projectname>]|[-workspace <workspacename>]] [-json]
  xcodebuild -showsdks
  xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <xcarchivepath> -exportPath <destinationpath> -exportOptionsPlist <plistpath>
  xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <path> -project <projectname> [-exportLanguage <targetlanguage>...]
  xcodebuild -importLocalizations -localizationPath <path> -project <projectname>
```

Comment: plz search on google you definitely find out

Comment: see `man xcodebuild`. Maybe `exportFormat` does not exist.

Comment: You're going to want to use `--exportArchive`,  `--exportFormat` doesn't exist, as the output is telling you. See the above linked issue for an example of how to set that up.

Answer (score 6):

A few things changed: `-exportFormat` and `-exportProvisioningProfile` don't exist anymore. Also, `-exportPath` now point to an actual path, not to a file.

You will have to create a plist file with your export options. This is an easy command-line way to do this:

```
echo "{\"method\":\"app-store\"}" | plutil -convert xml1 -o /tmp/exportOptions.plist -- -
```

Then use `-exportOptionsPlist /tmp/exportOptions.plist` in your call to `xcodebuild`.