# Xcode 10 - "Unknown Name" for team

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode10

In my projects target settings, when I select the provisioning profile I use to archive my application, I get a `Unknown Name` in the `team` field.

[image]

This is a provisionning profile my client sent me by email, and I do not have access to it's Apple Developer Account.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? 
Is there a way for my client to send me a "team provisioning profile" or so?

*Note: This **does not** prevent me to build/archive my project through Xcode. However, when trying to use `xcodebuild` command for continuous integration purposes, I get an error ( and I'm pretty sure it's linked to this weird configuration )*

**UPDATE**

I finally managed to make my `xcodebuild` command to work. It had nothing to do with this weird behavious in Xcode config. Also when unzipping my app archive, I can see that the embedded provisionning profile contains the good team name.

To sum up, this "error" doesn't prevent build to proceed. This is just Xcode being Xcode, I guess.

Comment: Are you configuring your CI to call the `xcodebuild` using `exportProvisioningProfile` correctly? Also, the error is specific with XCode 10 or it works correctly in XCode <10?

Comment: I use `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="MyProvisioningProfile"` instead of `exportProvisioningProfile` ( according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153881/5464805 )
I have not tried with other XCode versions, I specified it because I thought it could be relevant. 

The full error I get is `error: No profile for team ‘XXXXXX’ matching ‘My provisionning Profile’ found: Xcode couldn’t find any provisioning profiles matching ‘XXXXXX/My provisionning Profile’`, that's why I think its linked.
Also I am able to build other projects with `xcodebuild`, and this is the only difference I spoted.

Comment: Edited. Merci Cœur

Comment: @Olympiloutre Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @ChristopherR. It was a long ago but if I remember well I reinstalled my provisioning profiles and the error message disappeared on XCode. Afterwards the error for `xcodebuild` was linked to something else: I launched this command inside a shell script, which asked for a prompt that was never showing up.